# Compiler errors using Spotify SDK with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, spotify

I followed all of the steps to get the Spotify SDK working on swift from [this guide](https://medium.com/@elonrubin/ios-spotify-sdk-swift-3-0-tutorial-b629af4b889d), and now I have four compiler errors.

Here is any image of my code and compiler errors.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For your first error it looks like you are missing some parameters in your addObserver function call, specifically the name and object parameters.

2) Second error, you are calling the object(forKey) method without an instance of UserDefaults. See: http://www.thomashanning.com/userdefaults/ for a detailed explanation of how UserDefaults works. 
Try doing this "UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Key")"

3) Your third and fourth error seem to be self explanatory. This usually means your ViewController does not conform the the SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate and the SPTAudioStreamingDelegate. 
In your class declaration you should change it from:

class TestSpotifyViewController: UIViewController {

to:

class TestSpotifyViewController: UIViewController, SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate, SPTAudioStreamingDelegate